# Compiling Emacs on Snow Leopard

Tags: emacs, osx-snow-leopard, compilation

Has anyone successfully compiled the latest CVS version of Emacs on Snow Leopard? If so, could you provide instructions? I was using the following on Leopard, and it worked fine:

```
cvs -z3 -d:pserver:anonymous@cvs.sv.gnu.org:/sources/emacs co emacs
cd emacs
./configure --enable-carbon-app --with-ns --with-jpeg=no --with-gif=no \
            --with-tiff=no
make bootstrap
make
sudo make install
sudo cp -r nextstep/Emacs.app /Applications/Emacs.app
```

but this no longer works on Snow Leopard.

Comment: Um, what part of that no longer works?

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific. When I run 'make bootstrap', or if I skip that and run 'make', either way it crashes when compiling 'nsterm.m':

In file included from nsterm.h:20,
                 from nsterm.m:41:
dispextern.h:1250: error: array type has incomplete element type

The main problem with all the patches that I can find is that they are of course outdated as soon as there is a change in the cvs server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, there are pre-build binaries of Emacs that work on Snow Leopard, such as http://emacsformacosx.com/

The patches that are available in various places only work for specific CVS revisions most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of any other information, check out [this thread](http://trac.macports.org/ticket/20936) which details Emacs/Snow Leopard problems and their ultimate resolution.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to look at [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/), which currently has a beta for the latest Emacs and offers somewhat better OS X integration than the default build.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one option in your configure step:

```
./configure --with-ns CC='gcc -arch i386' --with-jpeg=no --with-gif=no --with-tiff=no
```

emacs has not been not released yet for the mac 64 bit architecture

--enable-carbon-app is also unnecessary now